# How to add button to Textview dynamically

Tags: sapui5

I have a question here, i need to add some button to the TextView in my tree table header row, the color of Button should be changed according to the line items rows(child nodes) data. 
How could that possible? please anyone help me on this.

```
<TextView id="idKuljkiel" semanticColor="Critical" text="{path:'zstrv_fun>KuljKiel', formatter:'.zchangeColor'}" />
```

I have created formatter function where i can write some code to create a button, but i am unable to add button to the TextView, and the color of the button should be changed as traffic lights.

For example if childrows have "X" or "" then Yellow,
if childrows have "X" or "X" then Green
if childrows have "" or "" then Red
Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You cannot add a Button or any other control to a TextView. It does not support child controls.
- In a formatter you should not modify the view. Its meant to just format a value. It should be idempotent.
- The `Button` control does not support arbitrary colors. It has a [style](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.commons.Button.html#getStyle) property that lets you change the button to red (reject), green (accept) or gray (default). colors depend on the theme.

Yout can put the TextView together with a Button into a HorizontalLayout. You can then bind the [visible](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Control.html#getVisible) property of the Button to your model (and use a formatter if needed).

```xml
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.ui.commons" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout">
...
  <l:HorizontalLayout>
    <TextView id="idKuljkiel" semanticColor="Critical" text="{path:'zstrv_fun>KuljKiel', formatter:'.zchangeColor'}" />
    <Button visible="{path:'zstrv_fun>WhatEver', formatter:'.zbuttonVisible'}" style="{path:'zstrv_fun>Bla', formatter:'.zbuttonStyle'}"/>
  </l:HorizontalLayout>
...
</mvc:View>
```

Dependig on your data structure inside your model it might be possible to bind to the whole row object and use that in the formatter. Otherwise it could be necessary to process the model data after load to calculate additional properties on the header rows.

Comment: Hello schnoedel, i am unable to get the solution can you please share a example for that..
Or i can share my model structure.. can you provide solution

Comment: Yes, please share more details of your model structure and more code of your view (the relevant parts of the tree table).

Comment: Hello schnoedel, please find the structure of my model for tree creation and related coding in view in the following link. 
https://jsfiddle.net/q38854fn/1/

Comment: Im still guessing whats the outcome of `convertToTreeTableResultData()`. But i've created a working example [on JSBin](https://jsbin.com/boleqarosa/2/edit?html,js,output). Please modify the data if it does not reflect your actual structure and i'll see what i can do.